# Time Series Clustering

Tags: time-series, clustering

The thing that I am trying to do is the time series shapes classification.

Basically the problem is as following:

Let's say I have some time series and my goal is to have an algorithm that "finds" the similar shapes in the data, that occur throughout the dataset and labels it accordingly (a, b, c...etc.)...The image might be worth than 1000 words, so I have attached the workflow that I have in mind

[image: classification]

It would be great if anyone directs me to the algorithms/papers/codes that deal with this kind of problems

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for something similar and found a couple of libraries (https://matrixprofile.org/libraries/) that might work but I haven’t tried them out much yet.

I hope that helps and if anyone has any other suggestions I’d be interested as well.